# Responsive two-column in mobile html

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to set two images in two column in mobile but doesn't work any idea?

[Demo here](http://jsbin.com/mebarizami/edit?html,css,output)

**HTML**

```
 <table bgcolor="#ffffff" id="event-info" class="outer-table"
     summary="outer-table"  valign="top" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="background-color:#ffffff; width:100%; max-width:600px; Margin:0 auto" width="100%">
                  <tr align="center" class="tab1">
                     <td>
                        <img src="images/website.png" class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:30%;max-width:600px;">
                        <p class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:35%;max-width:600px;
                        font-size: 12px;padding-top: 10px;font-weight: 700;">Website</p>
                      </td>
                       <td>
                        <img src="images/mobile.png" class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:30%;max-width:600px;">
                        <p class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:35%;max-width:600px;
                        font-size: 12px;padding-top: 10px;font-weight: 700;">Mobile</p>
                      </td>
                       <td>
                        <img src="images/marketing.png" class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:30%;max-width:600px;">
                        <p class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:35%;max-width:600px;
                        font-size: 12px;padding-top: 10px;font-weight: 700;">Marketing</p>
                      </td>
                     </tr>
                         <tr align="center"  class="tab2">
                     <td>
                        <img src="images/support.png" class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:30%;max-width:600px;">
                        <p class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:35%;max-width:600px;
                        font-size: 12px;padding-top: 10px;font-weight: 700;">Support</p>
                      </td>
                       <td>
                        <img src="images/management.png" class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:30%;max-width:600px;">
                        <p class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:35%;max-width:600px;
                            font-size: 12px;padding-top: 10px;font-weight: 700;">Management</p>
                      </td>
                       <td>
                        <img src="images/customer.png" class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:30%;max-width:600px;">
                        <p class="features" border="0" width="600" style="width:35%;max-width:600px;
                        font-size: 12px;padding-top: 10px;font-weight: 700;">Customer</p>
                      </td>
                      <tr class="spacer-40" height="40" style="height:55px; padding: 0 !important; margin: 0 !important; font-size: 0 !important; line-height: 0 !important;">
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      </tr>
                     </tr>
    </table>
```

**CSS**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 769px){  
    table tr td{
                  display:block;
                }


 }
```

Comment: demo update http://jsbin.com/sitibecobo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Why inline styles? ... Is this for an email?

Comment: You can't do that with a table as they have a row which divide them in 3:rd's in the first place. You need to skip table and use either `inline-block` or preferable `flexbox`. Do you want me to post a `flex` solution?

Comment: @LGSon yes for email

Answer (score 0):

Update based on comment

Since you can't switch a table from a 3 column to a 2 column layout (at least not in a proper way) and half of the email clients doesn't support media queries, I came up with this solution.

Test it thoroughly with email clients as I haven't been able to do that

*I added `min-width: 100px;` to the "tabs" divs which will make it break into 1 column when lack of space. Remove it if you don't want that.*

```html
<div style="max-width:600px;margin:0 auto;text-align: center;">
  <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:center;width:calc(100% - 4px);max-width:150px;min-width: 100px;">
    <img src="images/website.png" style="border:0;width:30%;">
    <p style="font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:center;width:calc(100% - 4px);max-width:150px;min-width: 100px;">
    <img src="images/website.png" style="border:0;width:30%;">
    <p style="font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:center;width:calc(100% - 4px);max-width:150px;min-width: 100px;">
    <img src="images/website.png" style="border:0;width:30%;">
    <p style="font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:center;width:calc(100% - 4px);max-width:150px;min-width: 100px;">
    <img src="images/website.png" style="border:0;width:30%;">
    <p style="font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:center;width:calc(100% - 4px);max-width:150px;min-width: 100px;">
    <img src="images/website.png" style="border:0;width:30%;">
    <p style="font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div style="display:inline-block;text-align:center;width:calc(100% - 4px);max-width:150px;min-width: 100px;">
    <img src="images/website.png" style="border:0;width:30%;">
    <p style="font-size:12px;padding-top:10px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">Website</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

<strike>As that can't be done properly using `table`, here is a `flex` solution.</strike>

```css
.outer {
  max-width:600px;
  margin:0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.outer .tab1 {
  width: 33%;
  text-align: center;
}
.outer img.features {
  border:0;
  width:30%;
  max-width:600px;
}
.outer p.features {
  max-width:600px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .outer .tab1 {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="event-info" class="outer">
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

If `flex` can't be used, use `display: inline-block`

```css
.outer {
  max-width:600px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.outer .tab1 {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: calc(33% - 4px);     /*  4px, see comment below  */
}
.outer img.features {
  border:0;
  width:30%;
  max-width:600px;
}
.outer p.features {
  max-width:600px;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;  
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
  .outer .tab1 {
    width: calc(50% - 4px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="event-info" class="outer">
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab1">
    <img src="images/website.png" class="features">
    <p class="features">Website</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Side note:

The 4px used, is to compensate for the white space (the line break between elements in the markup) and is based on font size, so if it increases this value might need to be adjusted.

An alternative is to change the markup from

```
</div>
<div class="tab1">
```

to

```
</div><div class="tab1">
```

or

```
</div><!--
--><div class="tab1">
```

Comment: I'm using table for email can u set with table ?